# ImageView with rounded edge Circle ripple

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, ripple

I'm trying to imitate this effect:

[image]

But I'm not able to, I've been doing this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="#fff"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any custom background just use an ImageButton like this:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:src="..."/>
```

You may need to add a padding as well.

Comment: `android:focusable="true"` and `android:clickable="true"` are also needed.

Comment: I did as you said, but it does not work.
<ImageButton
            android:id="@id/exo_play"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/play"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_play_36dp" />

Comment: @TheWanderer you don't need clickable it will be automatically set to true once you add a click listener and focusable only if you wanna navigate to button with a keyboard

Comment: SamuelEminet I've never had it work without those attributes. @Paul try using `?android:attr/...`

Comment: @SamuelEminet:     <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

I get no effect using "?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"

Comment: Make sure your ripple color is not the same as your background you can add this line from your theme to change color `<item name="colorControlHighlight">.../item>`

Comment: @SamuelEminet: I'll explain better what I want to do.
As you can see in the gif.
What I have to do this.
The background of the button must be transparent, only when you click on the button, you must see the ripple effect that you see in the image. But it must be rounded.


You could give me a clearer example.

Comment: @Paul it works perfectly as is, check this git project i just created https://github.com/SamYStudiO/ripple

Comment: @SamuelEminet: Thank you, I did as you say: https://pastebin.com/KuC7VwD8
But it just does not do anything on the button, no ripple anything.
It can depend on the build.gradle: https://pastebin.com/vYC7cved

I do not understand why, why it's not working.

Comment: @SamuelEminet: I think I understand what could be the reason why it does not work.
I'm using exoplayer, I'm overwriting the player's layout. It seems like the overheating buttons do not support "selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" somehow, because nothing happens.